# getting "undefined method `auth_code' for "Client function":String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

I am trying to run a simple authentication call to retrieve profiles via linkedin. 
   I am running ruby on rails and tried the example "http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/code-samples" explained here.

When running my code, i get an this error
   `` undefined method `auth_code' for "Client function":String ``

I have included in my GemFile the following:

```
   gem 'linkedin'
   gem 'oauth2'
   gem 'oauth'
```

With the following code:

```
 #Instantiate your OAuth2 client Object
  def client 
    OAuth2::Client.new(
      CONSUMER_KEY,
      CONSUMER_SECRET,
      :authorize_url => "/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code",
      :token_url => "/uas/oauth2/accessToken",
      :site => "https://www.linkedin.com"
    )   
    pp 'Client function'
  end 

  def test1
    pp ' to authorize function'
    authorize
  end 

  def authorize
    pp 'in authorize'
    #Redirect user in order to authenticate
    redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url(:scope => 'r_fullprofile r_emailaddress r_network',
                                               :state => STATE,
                                               :redirect_uri => REDIRECT_URI)
  end
```

So when it gets to redirect_to client.auth_code.authorize_url() i am getting undefined for "auth_code".

Any reason why this is? do i need another type of gem installed. I have tried bundle update and bundle install. Nothing is happening.

Any help is much appreciative. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client method returns the string "Client function" via the pp method instead of the client instance you create.

Comment: Appreciate it. dumb of me! new to ruby

Answer (score 1):

A ruby method returns the output of the last statement. In your case, it is the `pp` statement. Either remove the `pp` or put it at the beginning of the method.

Comment: You to as well. Thanx, appreciate it.